# Calling a static method of generic class with a dynamic type c#

Tags: c#, generics, types

```
public class A<T>
{
    public static void B()
    {
    }
}
```

How I can call method B like this:

```
Type C = typeof(SomeClass);
A<C>.B()
```

Comment: Can you add some context around the second code fragment, such as the declaration of C?

Comment: Is your intention to use: `A<SomeClass>.B();`? `C` is a variable, not a type.

Comment: @AlexFilipovici no. In future is may be a dynamic list of types and call this method for any of them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use reflection. `MakeGenericType` allows you to get the `Type` with specific generic arguments and then you can get and call any method on it as you like.

```
void Main()
{
    Type t = typeof(int);
    Type at = typeof(A<>).MakeGenericType(t);
    at.GetMethod("B").Invoke(null, new object[]{"test"});
}

public class A<T>
{
    public static void B(string s)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(s+" "+typeof(T).Name);
    }
}
```

As a performance optimization you could use reflection to get a delegate for each type which you then can invoke without further reflection.

```
Type t = typeof(int);
Type at = typeof(A<>).MakeGenericType(t);
Action<string> action = (Action<string>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action<string>), at.GetMethod("B"));
action("test");
```